# How do I find the display location (x,y) of an offset in a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

I have a DocumentListener that has access to the JTextPane containing the document.  In some cases the DocumentListener wants to pop up a list of commands that start with the string entered by the user.

The DocumentEvent has the character offset, but I need to convert this into an X,Y location to properly position the popup.

Currently the code uses textPane.modelToView(offset) to get a rectangle to get the location, but this is throwing NullPointerExceptions at times.

Is there another way to do this conversion?

Comment: Sorry, I missed part of your question last night. I've edited my answer - perhaps it's more helpful now.

Answer (score 2):

Try [JTextPane.modelToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#modelToView%28int%29).  To go the other way you'd use [JTextPane.viewToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#viewToModel%28java.awt.Point%29).

Oops...I missed the part where you said you were already using `modelToView`. I believe you can only use the conversion functions when your component is rendered and visible. Could that be causing your NPE?

Answer (score 2):

> Currently the code uses textPane.modelToView(offset) to get a rectangle to get the location, but this is throwing NullPointerExceptions at times.

Surround the popup showing and modelTOView() calls in the SwingUtilities.invokeLater. I guess sometime you ask for position but views layout is not finished yet.